# Manually Resume paused EXM email campaigns

Tags: exm

We have upgraded from Sitecore 9.3 to 10.3 after which the exm campaigns have moved to paused status.
How can i manually resume these campaigns?
I do not want an automated way of resuming the campaigns.

Comment: Do you mean automated or regular campaigns?

Comment: Its a regular campaign scheduled with recurring delivery

Comment: If you open that campaign in EXM on the `Delivery` tab, in the place where there is `Send Campaign` button, there should be now `Resume` button.

Comment: Thanks @MarekMusielak This resolved the issue

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following steps allow to resume any EXM message manually:

- Open your campaign in EXM.
- Switch to `Delivery` tab
- In the place where normally there is `Send Campaign` button, there will be now `Resume` button